# Google apps script. Как разделить информацию в ячейке на две с помощью split() в функции OnEdit?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, split

у меня в таблице есть 2 колонки: одна для имени, вторая для фамилии. Пытаюсь сделать следующее. Когда в ячейку колонки **"A"** я вставляю информацию вида **"Имя Фамилия"** то в автоматическом режиме текст разделяется и в ячейку **"B"** вставляется **"Фамилия"**, а в ячейке **"А"** текст **"Имя Фамилия" заменяется на "Имя"**. И так для каждой строки.
Вот код который у меня на данный момент есть:

```
    function onEdit(e) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = e.source.getSheetByName("Test");
    var idCol = e.range.getColumn();
    var idRow = e.range.getRow();
    if ( idCol == 1 ) {
     sheet.getRange(idRow, idCol +1).setValue(idCol.split(" "));
     var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Test");
     var target = targetSheet.getRange(idRow, idCol);
     sheet.getRange(idRow, idCol +1).moveTo(target);
     var target2 = targetSheet.getRange(idRow, idCol +1);
     sheet.getRange(idRow, idCol +2).moveTo(target);
   };    
};
```

Помогите разобраться, в чем ошибка и как заставить его работать. Если такое возможно.

Comment: как минимум можно сделать split(",", 1) запишет имя

Comment: Пробовал. Скрипт записывает имя, а фамилию теряет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вопрос самостоятельно. Вдруг кому пригодиться.
Вот код:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = e.source.getSheetByName("Test"); 
  var idCol = e.range.getColumn();
  var idRow = e.range.getRow();
  if (idCol == 1) {
    var nsplit = sheet.getRange(idRow, idCol).getValue(); 
    nsplit = nsplit.split(" ");
    sheet.getRange(idRow, idCol).setValue(nsplit[0]);
    sheet.getRange(idRow, idCol +1).setValue(nsplit[1]);
  };
};
```